# How to handle: Warning MSB3182: File name 'Resources\....File.txt' exceeds 100 characters

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, warnings

I have a WPF project with a couple large strings in it.

So I decided to clean it up a bit and move my strings into some constant fields.

Then I decided; hey... maybe it's better if I move each of the really big strings into its own '`.txt`' file; then add those '`.txt`' files in as resources in my project. Then I'll just read in the big strings from the '`.txt'` files in the resources.

Upon building I get this warning in the '`Error List`' :

> Warning - File name 'Resources\Templates\ReviewTemplates\ReviewApplicationDocumentTemplates\SingleApplicationTemplateDocumentOne.txt' exceeds 100 characters.

I need some advice so I can figure out what's the best, most proper, clean way to handle my large strings.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you're reading that txt file line-by-line or something, otherwise moving it into an embedded resource seems a little pointless

Comment: It's complaining about the length of the file name anyway, which you haven't shown us (you truncated it with "..."). Reduce the length of the file *name* so it's less than 100 characters. The contents of the file are irrelevant here

Comment: Ok I've checked: My .txt file name is less that 100 characters, but the path from 'Resources' to .txt is more than 100 characters.

Comment: When it says `Warning - File name 'Resources...File.txt' exceeds 100 characters`, can you post that again but don't replace characters with `...`?

Comment: I've edited my question and added in the full warning. I have many ordered hierarchies and very descriptive names.

Comment: Right, the stuff between quotes is what matters and that's over 100 chars

Comment: Are you putting your string into an embedded resource so that you can read it line by line, or are you still reading it back into a string?

Comment: I'm reading it into a string variable, then manipulating that string.

Comment: There's no point in using an embedded resource then: you're just loading it into ram multiple times instead of once. If you're manipulating it, that's even more copies. Either the string is small enough that it's fine as a literal, or it's large enough that you have to make sure you don't load it all into memory at once. It sounds like you're in the first category, so I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226254/discussion-between-shiasu-sama-and-canton7).